# Problems Updating content of table cell

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I was just playing around with IOS and I hit a problem and it seems so simple that I can't believe it's not working

I have a table list
I have set up all the delegate so that it displays information from a plist

that works

however when I switched to my custom view for the internal layout, I get the default text of the view but not the text form the plist

Here is some code of the table view controller:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"DefaultCell"];

    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"DefaultCell"];
    }

        EmergencyContactItemConrtroller *genericViewController = [[EmergencyContactItemConrtroller alloc] initWithNibName:@"EmergencyContactItemConrtroller" bundle:nil];

[genericViewController setInitialParametersWithTitle:[[emergencyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"Title"]
                                        withCatption:[[emergencyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"Caption"]
                                          withNumber:[[emergencyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"Number"]
                                       withOtherInfo:nil];

[cell.contentView addSubview:genericViewController.view];

return cell;

}
```

and here is the code of setInitialParametersWithTitle in the cell view controller.

```
-(void) setInitialParametersWithTitle:(NSString *)title
                         withCatption:(NSString *)caption 
                           withNumber:(NSString *)number
                        withOtherInfo:(NSDictionary *)otherInfo{
    self.titleLable.text = title;
    self.captionLable.text = caption;
    [self.numberButton setTitle:number forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

I checked that the xib IBOutlet are linked correctly.

when I try to debug I get he right values send to the function, how ever when I printout self.titleLable.text **before** assigning a value to it, there is no value in it.

Any Ideas ?

Jason

Comment: Does the emergencyArray contain the necessary information? Did you check that?

Comment: EmergencyContactItemConrtroller is UIViewController class? All IBOutlets will initialized after [cell.contentView addSubview:genericViewController.view] is done; Then you should change them.

Comment: @NeverBe: It worked, Thanks ( do you want to post your comment as an answer ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EmergencyContactItemConrtroller is UIViewController class? 
All IBOutlets will initialized after

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:genericViewController.view]
```

is done; Then you should change them

Answer (score 1):

Try to reload your table view in `-(void)viewwillappear()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, inside if(cell==nil),

```
if(cell == nil){
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"DefaultCell"];
    cell.contentView = [[UIView alloc]init];
}
```

Then you can add subView above cell's contentView